# MacOS Swift App on XCode 14.1: Cannot read user selected file

Tags: swift, macos, readfile

I have a pretty simple app that lets the user select a file and display it using the NSOpenPanel. It is sandboxed but I have checked to allow for user selected files:

```
com.apple.security.files.user.-selected.read-write Boolean YES
```

Here is the code for the dialog:

```
func chooseFile() -> String?  {
    
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel();

    dialog.title                   = "Choose multiple files | Our Code World";
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator    = true;
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles        = false;
    dialog.canChooseDirectories    = false;
    dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false;
    
    if (dialog.runModal() ==  NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
        
        // Results contains an array with all the selected paths
        let results = dialog.urls
        
        if results.count > 0 {
            return results[0].path
        }
        
    } else {
        // User clicked on "Cancel"
        return nil
    }
    
    return nil
    
}
```

and the code for reading/displaying the contents of the file:

```
@IBAction func openFile(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let strFilePath = myAppManager.chooseFile() {
        
        //make url
        let fileURL = URL(string: strFilePath)
        
        //get optional value
        if let fileURL = fileURL {
            
            //read the file
            do {
                let strFileContents = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
                txtView.string = strFileContents
                }
            catch {
                print("Error reading the file: \(strFilePath)")
                }
        } else {
            print("Error creating file URL from: \(strFilePath)")
        }
        
        
    } else {
        print("User cancelled file selection.")
    }
    
}
```

I keep getting these errors. This is for a rtf file, but it has also failed on a python (.py) file. Do I have to specify file type?

```
2022-11-22 09:55:20.463374-0500 MarsTyper[8565:189921] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
Error reading the file: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/test.rtf
```

**Extra complaint:**

@Apple - it is annoying to just put out an error code in your error messaging and then on your documentation page to just list the enums and not their associated code unless you click on each one.

```
NSURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile = -1102
```

Comment: Don't use paths, use `URL`s instead.

Comment: Thanks, make it an answer and I'll give you a bump!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of ``:

> Security-scoped URLs provide access to resources outside an app’s sandbox.

> If you need a security-scoped URL’s path as a string value (as provided by the path method), such as to provide to an API that requires a string value, obtain the path from the URL as needed. Note, however, that a string-based path obtained from a security-scoped URL does not have security scope and you cannot use that string to obtain access to a security-scoped resource.

So don't use the path, use the URL instead.